# Are there any issues with continually replacing an object in an array?

Tags: objective-c

I've got some code where I need to replace one object in an array with another. The code as it stands won't check if that object has already been replaced but instead will just keep replacing it, can this cause problems? and if so should I check to see if the array already contains the object and not replace if it does? The line I'm using is..

```
[subArray replaceObjectAtIndex:col withObject:obj];
```

I'm using ARC is that makes a difference.

Comment: What problems would it cause?

Comment: How many times are you calling this per second then?

Comment: I was wondering if there were any memory issues. It's part of a game loop so a good number of times per second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `replaceObjectAtIndex:` method retains the new object, releases the old object, and makes an assignment into the array that backs the `NSMutableArray`'s data. These operations will not cause memory issues even when the object being assigned is already stored in the array at the same position. These operations are performed very quickly, so checking equality before the assignment would likely be a waste of time.

Comment: `makes an assignment into the array that backs the NSMutableArray's data` I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: @abbood `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` allocate an array of `id` objects internally, and put your data into that array.